# PHP: How to send mail as a PDF?

Tags: php, email, pdf

I have a client questionnaire form with several input fields. When the form is submitted, I would like the message to be sent to me as a PDF. Is this possible? If so, does anyone have any references or links to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Create PDF and set it as attachment to the email. Google `email pdf php` - first result: http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/code/217105

Comment: I get this error with that script, any thoughts? Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Bad parameters to mail() function, mail not sent.

Answer (score 2):

Those are a some quite different problems in one question.

1. How to generate a pdf.
   Check out [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/).
2. How to send mail with attachments. 
   For that you will need to send a multi-part message. A part that is different from the main e-mail can contain the PDF. It will need a correct mime type to be treated as such. An example [is here](http://www.webcheatsheet.com/PHP/send_email_text_html_attachment.php#attachment).
3. The mime type of PDF, which is `application/pdf`.

I assumed you got the part with the questionnaire itself working already.

Comment: Thank you that helps out so much! I found an example that should work http://www.astahost.com/info.php/Create-Email-Pdf-File-39on-Fly39-Php_t6334.html , but the script is calling in a file called mail.php, and I don't know where that is coming from. The error is around line 58, & the error is with this piece of code  $mail = &Mail::factory('mail');

Comment: It is from PEAR (PHP Extension and Application Repository): http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail.factory.php

Comment: Thank You it works now! Would you know how to word wrap the text inside the PDF? I am using an array like:  
    $email_message =" fax: ".clean_string($fax)."\n<br/>";
    $email_message .="  address: ".clean_string($address)."\n<br/>";
    $email_message .="  email: ".clean_string($email)."\n<br/>";    
 but the break tags show up within the PDF, I would like each one to go on a new line. I appreciate your time.

Comment: PDF is not HTML, those <br> tags are HTML. Omit them. Use the FPDF MultiCell method to output multiple lines. It's all in the docs. :) http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/multicell.htm